# Syntax Errors Fluent UDF from Windows to Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, user-defined-functions, fluent

I currently use user defined functions in ANSYS Fluent. These are written in C language with some macros specific to fluent. I have working udfs written for windows, and am now trying to run them on a Linux machine. I have received the following errors. I am relatively new to Linux and C, so any help would be appreciated.

```
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:33:9: error: z undeclared    (first use in this function)
 if (z < anomaly_top_z + anomaly_accuracy_z)      return 0; 
     ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:25:7: warning: unused variable y [-Wunused-variable]
    real y = coords[1];  // convenient names for coordinates: horizontal, vertical
   ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:24:10: warning: unused variable x [-Wunused-variable]
 real x = coords[0]; 
      ^

    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:25:7: warning: unused variable y [-Wunused-variable]
    real y = coords[1];  // convenient names for coordinates: horizontal, vertical
   ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:24:10: warning: unused variable x [-Wunused-variable]
 real x = coords[0]; 
      ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:57:3: error: sal_val undeclared (first use in this function)
    sal_val = 7.0;
    ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:53:10: warning: unused variable depth [-Wunused-variable]
 real depth = coords[2];               // yes, sir - the depth is always the second in coords array

    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:65:2: warning: implicit declaration of function initTemperature [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    initTemperature(domain);

    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:67:6: warning: conflicting types for initTemperature [enabled by default]
    void initTemperature(Domain * domain) 
    ^
    cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:162:3: error: else without a previous if
    else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM)
    ^
```

Here is the code without the error lines:

```
    #include "udf.h"

    /*=======================================================================*/
    #define DEPTH_TOP -0.2
    #define DEPTH_BOTTOM -2.0
    #define MU_TOP 18
    #define MU_BOTTOM 1e-3
    #define r 25.0
    #define DIFFUSE_TOP 18
    #define DIFFUSE_BOTTOM 1.43e-6

    #ifdef RP_3D
    double anomaly_top_z =  -10.0; 
    double anomaly_bottom_z   =  0.0; 
    double anomaly_accuracy_z   = 0.1; 
    #endif

    /*=======================================================================*/
    enum
    {salinity,
    };
    int is_in_plume(double coords[])
    {
real x = coords[0]; 
real y = coords[1];  /* convenient names for coordinates: horizontal, vertical */

    #ifdef RP_3D
real z = coords[2];  /* convenient names for coordinates: second horizontal */
#endif

if ((pow((x-125.0),2)+pow((y-125),2))>pow(r,2))   return 0;

if (z < anomaly_top_z + anomaly_accuracy_z)      return 0; 
if (z > anomaly_bottom_z - anomaly_accuracy_z)   return 0; 

return 1; 
    }

    double temp_plume(double coords[]) 
    {
real depth = coords[2];               /* yes, sir - the depth is always the second in coords array */
real temp_val;   

if (is_in_plume(coords) == 1) {
    temp_val = 298.15;
} else {
    temp_val = 299.15; 
} 
    return temp_val;
    }
    double sal_plume(double coords[]) 
    {
real depth = coords[2];               /* yes, sir - the depth is always the second in coords array */
real sal_val;   

if (is_in_plume(coords) == 1) {
    sal_val = 7.0;
} else {
    sal_val = 27.0; 
} 
    return sal_val;
    }
    DEFINE_INIT(tempplume_init, domain)
    {
initTemperature(domain);
    }
    void initTemperature(Domain * domain) 
    {
real coords[ND_ND];                   /* will be used to get       coordinares */
real temp_val;                         /* temporary variable */
Thread* thread; 
cell_t cell;
int init_result = 1; 
real depth; 

if (init_result == -1) {
    Error("Initialization failed. \n"); 
} else { 
    Message("Start looping. \n");       
    thread_loop_c(thread, domain)                 /* loop over         all types ("threads") of cells in the domain */
    {
        Message("In loop over threads. \n"); 

        begin_c_loop_all(cell, thread)            /* loop over all cells in the thread */
            C_CENTROID(coords, cell, thread);     /*          load coordinates of the cell into "coords" array; */

            depth = coords[ND_ND - 1]; 

            temp_val = temp_plume(coords);  

            C_T(cell, thread) = temp_val;  
        end_c_loop_all(cell, thread)              /* end loop over cells */
    }                                             /* end loop over threads */

    Message("Initialization complete. \n"); 
} 
    }
    DEFINE_INIT(salplume_init, domain)
    {
initSalinity(domain);
    }
    void initSalinity(Domain * domain) 
    {
real coords[ND_ND];                   /* will be used to get coordinates */
real sal_val;                         /* temporary variable */
Thread* thread; 
cell_t cell;
int init_result = 1; 
real depth; 

if (init_result == -1) {
    Error("Initialization failed. \n"); 
} else { 
    Message("Start looping. \n");       
    thread_loop_c(thread, domain)                 /* loop over all types ("threads") of cells in the domain */
    {
        Message("In loop over threads. \n"); 

        begin_c_loop_all(cell, thread)            /* loop over all cells in the thread */
            C_CENTROID(coords, cell, thread);     /*        load coordinates of the cell into "coords" array; */

            depth = coords[ND_ND - 1]; 

            sal_val = sal_plume(coords);  

            C_UDSI(cell, thread,salinity) = sal_val;  
        end_c_loop_all(cell, thread)              /* end loop over cells */
    }                                             /* end loop over threads */

    Message("Initialization complete. \n"); 
} 
    }
    DEFINE_PROPERTY(salinity_dens,c,t)
    {
real pho_w, sigma_t;
real sal = C_UDSI(c,t,salinity); /* in promilles */
real temp = C_T(c,t) - 273.15; 

/* complex formula - see www.es.flinders.edu.au/~mattom/IntroOc/lecture03.html */

sigma_t = - 0.157406 + temp*(6.793952E-2 - temp*(9.095290E-3 - temp*(1.001685E-4 - temp*(1.120083E-6 - temp 
    *6.536332E-9)))) + 
   sal*(8.24493E-1 - temp*(4.0899E-3 - temp*(7.6438E-5 - temp*(8.2467E-7 - temp*5.3875E-9))) 
   - sqrt(sal)*(5.72466E-3 - temp*(1.0227E-4 - temp*1.6546E-6)) + sal*4.8314E-4);

pho_w = 1000.0 + sigma_t; 
return pho_w;
    }
    DEFINE_PROPERTY(cell_viscosity, c, ct)
    {
real mu_laminar; real depth;

real coords[ND_ND];      /* will be used to get coordinares */

C_CENTROID(coords, c, ct);  
/*depth = coords[1]; */

depth = coords[ND_ND - 1];            /* -2 because y is vertical */

    if (depth > DEPTH_TOP)
        mu_laminar = MU_TOP;
    else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM)
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM;
    else 
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM + (depth - DEPTH_BOTTOM) * 
               (MU_TOP - MU_BOTTOM)/(DEPTH_TOP - DEPTH_BOTTOM);
    return mu_laminar;
    }
    DEFINE_DIFFUSIVITY(sal_diffuse, c, ct, i)
{
real diffusivity; real depth;

real coords[ND_ND];      /* will be used to get coordinares */

C_CENTROID(coords, c, ct);  

depth = coords[ND_ND - 2];            /* -2 because y is vertical */

    if (depth > DEPTH_TOP)
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_TOP;
    else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM)
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_BOTTOM;
    else 
        diffusivity = DIFFUSE_BOTTOM + (depth - DEPTH_BOTTOM) * 
               (DIFFUSE_TOP - DIFFUSE_BOTTOM)/(DEPTH_TOP -         DEPTH_BOTTOM);

    return diffusivity;
    }

    DEFINE_SOURCE(x_mom,c,t,dS,eqn)
    {
real coords[ND_ND];
real y = coords[1]; 
real f; real theta; real source;
theta=10.0*3.14/180.0;
f=2.0*7.2921e-5*sin(theta)*50.0;
source=C_R(c,t)*f*C_V(c,t);
dS[eqn]=0.0;
return source;
    }

    DEFINE_SOURCE(y_mom,c,t,dS,eqn)
    {
real coords[ND_ND];
real x = coords[0]; 
real f; real theta; real source;
theta=10.0*3.14/180.0;
f=-2.0*7.2921e-5*sin(theta)*50.0;
source=C_R(c,t)*f*C_U(c,t);
dS[eqn]=0.0;
return source;
    }
```

Comment: Are you running the software in 2d mode ? for the `real sal_val`, you should probably run the `DEFINE_INIT` macro first ( as far as i remember it is done at initialization ) before running the computation. Also i would double check that all your UDF are properly hooked ( momentum equation for your source terms, material properties and so on ..)

Comment: I am running it in 3D. I will implement the DEFINE_INIT macro. The UDF works fine on windows but when compiling it on Linux it displays the many syntax errors. I have not even been able to compile it to actually hook it when running on Linux yet.

Comment: Ok, how do you recompile your UDF ? from the GUI/TUI or from a Makefile outside of the software ?

Comment: I worked with someone from ANSYS to troubleshoot this initially, and she recommended saving my .c file in the directory I am working with, then just compiling the code under compiled in Fluent. Loading the udf and then creating the libudf library.

Comment: Yes, rebuilding your library from scratch is a good start. Once it is compiled then load it before running the computation. Doing all of this from within the Ansys Fluent GUI would be easier

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:33:9: error: z undeclared    (first use in this function)
> ```

The corresponding declaration of variable `z` is wrapped in a conditional compilation directive:

> ```
>     #ifdef RP_3D
> real z = coords[2];  /* convenient names for coordinates: second horizontal */
> #endif
> ```

It is unclear what is expected to cause the macro `RP_3D` to be defined (also affecting some other declarations), and it is even more unclear why the declarations would be guarded by conditional compilation directives when their *uses* are not.  But it appears that for this code to compile correctly it is *required* that the macro `RP_3D` be defined or the conditional compilation directives related to it be removed.  The quickest resolution for this problem would be to put a

```
#define RP_3D 1
```

Near the top of the C source file.  It's unclear whether it must precede the `#include` directive, may precede it, or must not precede it -- any of these are possible, depending on the contents of the file being included.

Alternatively, protecting all uses of the z-axis-related variables with conditional compilation directives, too, would be appropriate if you must support the case where macro `RP_3D` is not defined.  That is, instead of ensuring that the variables are always declared, you can ensure that when they are not declared, they also are not referenced.

---

> ```
> warning: unused variable [...]
> ```

To a first approximation, all these warnings can be ignored.

---

> ```
> cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:57:3: error: sal_val undeclared (first use in this function)
> ```

This does not make sense.  The variable in question appears to have been declared three lines earlier, putting the the uses in the body of the function, including at line 57, inside the scope of that declaration.  If this persists after the other errors are resolved then make sure that the two variable names are in fact identical.  Look for look-alike characters in them with different character codes, and check for non-printing characters within.  Or maybe just retype both the declaration and the use(s).

---

> ```
> cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:65:2: warning: implicit declaration of function initTemperature [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> initTemperature(domain);
>
> cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:67:6: warning: conflicting types for initTemperature [enabled by default]
> void initTemperature(Domain * domain) 
> ^
> ```

These arise from a call to function `initTemperature()` appearing before the definition (or any forward declaration) of that function.  Although they are warnings, not errors, they should definitely be addressed.  To that end, it is suspicious that the call appears immediately before the definition, in a function named `DEFINE_INIT`.  Moving the `DEFINE_INIT` function *after* function `initTemperature()` should resolve that issue.

---

> ```
> cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity.c:162:3: error: else without a previous if
> else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM)
> ^
> ```

The reason for this error is unclear.  The `else` clause *does* appear to be associated with an immediately-preceding `if` statement.  Nevertheless, it would be better form (for all your `if` and `else` statements) to use brace-enclosed blocks instead of bare statements.  Example:

```
    if (depth > DEPTH_TOP) {
        mu_laminar = MU_TOP;
    } else if (depth < DEPTH_BOTTOM) {
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM;
    } else {
        mu_laminar = MU_BOTTOM + (depth - DEPTH_BOTTOM) * 
               (MU_TOP - MU_BOTTOM)/(DEPTH_TOP - DEPTH_BOTTOM);
    }
```

I don't expect that to solve this particular problem, but it is reasonable to hope that it will cause a different error message to be emitted that more clearly conveys the nature of the underlying issue.

Comment: The `RP_3D` is automatically set when the software runs in 3d mode

Comment: @Scab, `RP_3D` is used as if it were a macro.  That will not work as you presumably want if it is actually a variable.  Conditional compilation directives are evaluated at *compile* time, and therefore cannot take into account any information that varies from run to run.

Comment: When you compile the UDF you can compile it in 3d or 2d mode actually. You can do it from the GUI of the software or build it outside of it with a proper Makefile ( examples are usually provided by Ansys )

Comment: Ok then, a third alternative for resolving the errors related to that is to guard all the *uses* of the z-axis-related variables with conditional compilation directives, too.  As the code currently stands, the variables' declarations are sometimes suppressed and sometimes not, but the program always tries to use them.  I will add that to the answer.

Comment: To be more clear, if the OP compiles it's UDF from the GUI or TUI, `RP_3D` is set if the software was launched in 3d mode.

Comment: @Scab, you seem to be going back and forth.  I will try to be as clear as possible: it is whether the identifier `RP_3D` is defined as a macro, at compile time, that determines the effect of the `#ifdef` conditional compilation directives in your code.  That effect is fully realized when the program is compiled, without relying on any information that is determined only when the program runs.

Comment: ...   *Moreover*, the code presented in the question is flawed in this area, because it provides an opportunity -- which you experienced -- for some variable declarations to be suppressed without also suppressing all uses of those variables.  If the variables are used in any way, then they must first be declared.

Comment: Yes `RP_3D` is a macro defined at compile time. But there are several ways to compile those plugins from the GUI and some compiler directives are set according to the runtime mode of the software ( 3d, 2d, 3ddp, 2ddp, serial or parallel). Of course you can do it outside of the software, relying on the makefiles and examples provided by Ansys ( and you can set if you want 2d or 3d mode, etc..) but you never explicitly set `#define RP_3D 1`

Comment: Ok, @Scab.  I have already responded -- both here in comments and by updating this answer -- to how to approach the related errors in the event that you must rely on `RP_3D`'s definition status to be externally determined.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I am currently implementing them into my code and will then re-run for updated errors.

Comment: I have re-ran the code and the following errors still arose: 'cylinder_plume_inccoriolis_viscosity_test.c:65:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token' I am not sure why this occurred at only two spots in the code since I use { often throughout. The warning of conflicting types for 'initTemperature' has now shifted to an error.